# Сколько стоит получить данные с сервера

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Отправляю на сервер запрос для получения времени, и получаю в таком формате

> 2019-02-28-16-51-11

вопрос, сколько мобильных данных я потратил? (сколько байтов либо кб это затратило, учитывая отправку запроса с помощью UnityWebRequest). Потому как я представляю по одному (либо двум) байтам за символ и потому что мне выдают настройки приложения, разница большая.

Comment: А служебные данные вы не учитываете что ли? У вас http заголовков отправляется на порядок больше, чем самих данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А давайте проведём эксперимент и посчитаем общую длину переданных данных. Для начала нам потребуется установленная программа [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) — откроем её. Убедимся, что у нас в системе есть утилита [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) — воспользуемся ей для отправки HTTP-запроса вместо вашего UnityWebRequest. Такое упрощение только для целей демонстрации, и оно не вносит существенных искажений в результат. Для запроса времени обратимся к публичному [World Time API](http://worldtimeapi.org/).

Когда всё будет готово, начинаем! Закройте все программы, которые каким-либо образом подключаются к Интернету и запустите захват пакетов в Wireshark, нажав на кнопку с плавником в левом верхнем углу на панели инструментов. Откройте терминал и выполните команду `curl http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip.txt`. Вернитесь в Wireshark и остановите захват пакетов. Теперь давайте посмотрим на результат.

[image: Список захваченных пакетов]

Мы видим, что, чтобы узнать время таким образом, было передано 14 пакетов, общей длиной 1896 байт. Потерь, судя по всему, не было. Было отправлено 2 DNS-запроса и получено 2 DNS-ответа. Затем, когда компьютер узнал IP-адрес сервера, с помощью ещё трёх пакетов было установлено TCP-соединение. Потом был отправлен HTTP-запрос ресурса `/api/ip.txt`. Далее к нам пришло подтверждение получения запроса и отдельно ответ (вместе со всеми заголовками, естественно). В конце уже мы отправили подтверждение получения ответа и инициировали закрытие TCP-соединения.

Поэтому даже если вы максимально сожмёте формат времени, всё равно гораздо больше останется накладных расходов. В нашем случае соотношение длины содержимого ответа к общему количеству переданных данных составило примерно 10,6 %. Только десятую часть переданных данных мы увидели в выводе cURL.

У российских мобильных операторов  1 МБ переданных данных стоит в районе 10,89 руб. Если пересчитать на наш объём, то получится, что мы потратили чуть более чем 2 коп. Правда, нужно учесть округление в большую сторону до 10 кБ, но помимо нашего запроса может быть отправлено и что-нибудь другое в рамках одной интернет-сессии. Если подключить пакет трафика, то можно сэкономить.

Внимательный читатель заметит, что эксперимент был проведён не совсем вчистую, по Wi-Fi и в уютной домашней обстановке, но для мобильного интернета применимы аналогичные рассуждения. Разве что связь может быть менее стабильной, а потери пакетов более вероятны. Соответственно, будет ещё больше накладных расходов.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибку в оценке вы делаете потому, что не представляете себе накладных расходов сетевого обмена.
Вам стоит разобраться в устройстве протоколов и сетевых уровней, учавствовавших в обмене. Например, вдумчиво прочитать "компьютерные сети" Таненбаума. Что соотвествует примерно курсу по сетям для программистов в профтехе. После первых двух глав вы будете понимать, почему это произошло. После всех остальных, понимать все детали случившегося.

Очень кратно не получится, но я попробую: Передача данных по сети - сложная комплексная задача. С очень большим количеством аспектов. Люди научились её решать с помощью декомпозиции - разбив большую сложную задачу на несколько более простых. Для каждой из получившихся задач используется набор программ. Все они добавляют к вашим, полезным данным свои, не нужные с точки зрения потребителя, но необходимые им для функционирования. Представьте, что вы хотите отправить письмом по почте одну букву. С гарантией доставки. Вам понадобится конверт, на котором вы напишете служебные данные для отправки: адресс и т.д. Выходит, к вашей одной букве уже на этой стадии добавилась куча букв, никак не связанных со смыслом сказанного, но нужных чтобы сообщение дошло. Что то добавят еще на почте, что то в аэропорту и т.д.

Если вы работаете с веб реквестами, посредников, которые добавляют "свой конверт" - около 10. Кроме того, самих "писем" оказывается нужно больше одного. Если брать самую верхушку, чтобы выполнить ваш веб реквест, нужно устрановить надежное соединение с сервером (которое исправляет ошибки, если они случаются в сети). Это ряд "писем" (пакетов) туда сюда. Послать запрос и получить ответ. Затем разорвать соединение. 
Вот и получается, что вы видите верхушку айсберга: вес бумаги, на которой напечатан ответ, но при замере трафика выдается вес со всеми "конвертами" учавствовавшими в прошедшей служебной переписке.